# asp.net passing paramets to generic handler throgh jquery ajax

Tags: asp.net

Hi I have been going through this article:
[asp.net jquery ajax json: Simple example of exchanging data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11269622/asp-net-jquery-ajax-json-simple-example-of-exchanging-data)

I am also using same code problem that is I am able to pass values to my handler and when i see values in handler using breakpoint everything is working fine but I am not getting values returned by handler 
My javascript code is:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
     jQuery("#<%=btnsubmit.ClientID %>").click(function () {

         var myData = { "hicode": $('#textbox1 ').val() };

         $.ajax({
             url: "HandlerHinditoEnglish.ashx",
             data: myData,

             type: 'POST',

             success: function (data) {

                 $("#textbox2").val(data);
             },
             error: function (data, status, jqXHR) { alert("FAILED:" + status); }
         });
     });
```

and handler code is

```
        HttpResponse r = context.Response;
        r.ContentType = "text/plain";

        string Hinditext = string.Empty;
        string Englishtext = string.Empty;
        string myPar = context.Request.Form["hicode"]; 
        Hinditext = myPar;
        Englishtext = hcnvrt.ToEnglish(Hinditext).ToString();

        context.Response.Write(Englishtext);
```

I want to do is if i enter some text in `textbox1`, `textbox2` should get filled with the same value.

Comment: Are you sure your text boxes IDs are `textbox1` and `textbox2`? Please check or post the relevant HTML.

Comment: textbox naming is not an issue i have changed textbox names before posting

Answer (score 0):

If you put your Ajax code in `$(document).ready` you can see that it's working fine, but when you put it in `.click` event it cause error. It's becuase the default behavior of button.

In order to solve this problem you need to prevent the default behavior of your button when clicking so add `e` parameter to `.click` function and also add `e.preventDefault(e);`.

Your final code must be look like this:

```
jQuery("#<%=btnsubmit.ClientID %>").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault(e);
    var myData = { "hicode": $('#<%=textbox1.ClientID %>').val() };
    $.ajax({
        url: "HandlerHinditoEnglish.ashx",
        data: myData,
        type: 'POST',
        success: function (data) {
            $("#<%=textbox2.ClientID %>").val(data);
        },
        error: function (data, status, jqXHR) { alert("FAILED:" + status); }
    });
});
```