# Creating .json file

Tags: c#, json

I have created JSON using following code.

```
List<int> _data = new List<int>();
        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            _data.Add((int)row["Id"]);
        }
        JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        chartData = jss.Serialize(_data);
```

Now can anyone tell me how do I save this is something like data.json? I want to write it into a file.

Comment: `System.IO.File.WriteAllText("data.json", chartData);`

Comment: And where it will be saved? I mean in the solution?

Comment: In the working directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Serialize` method returns a `String`, doesn't it? So you can just use [`File.WriteAllText()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143375%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: it executed but not finding the file. I want to use it in the javascript

Comment: @Saumil what have executed?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Can you give a little more context? _Who_ doesn't find the file? And where does the JS come from you want to use the JSON in?

Comment: I wrote `File.WriteAllText("data.json",chartData);` the code executed without any error but not getting the file.

Comment: The file will be placed in the current working directory, most likely in your `bin\Debug` or `bin\Release` folder where the current `.exe` file is located (if it's a "Windows executable" project). You may want to specify a full path instead of just `"data.json"`.

Comment: It is an aspx page and I am performing this in .cs file. I want to call this .json extension file using Ajax and use the datafrom the file for displying it on highchart.

Comment: Then you don't have to save the file to hard disk (that makes no sense). It has to be created on-the-fly within the web request because the `aspx` which is called from HighChart must contain the JSON data. So the `aspx` file must return the JSON string, and no HTML or anything else. Nothing needs to be saved to a file.

Comment: Well I tried that way I called the aspx page but I am not getting success in it.

Comment: The function on success of Ajax call is not executing

Comment: OK, but this isn't related to your original question anymore. Maybe you should ask a question on how to perform an AJAX call with JSON result in an ASP.NET project - because you already _have_ the JSON that must be returned (it's the `chartData` string).

Comment: May be this question is suitable for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5756147/basic-simple-asp-net-jquery-json-example